# sharepoint is loading working on it dialog for no reason

Tags: sharepoint-server

sometimes when i am trying to fill up a form in sharepoint webparts, suddenly sharepoint will show "working on it" and reload the page so my entered data will gone. why it is happening and how can i stop it or at least keep my entered data?
[image]

Comment: Any scripts inserted in that page?

Comment: it's happening in whole site, not just in specific page. @KarthikJaganathan

Comment: Any scripts inserted in the master page??

Comment: ofcourse there are some scripts in master page but what is the point? do you mean a script may cause it? how can i detect it? @KarthikJaganathan

Comment: Apart from the default SharePoint scripts, have you injected any custom scripts in that?? If so please do check that.